# Django link gets appended to URL

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django for a project, and am trying to make a link to a page called "index" which is the starting page from the page with an url

```
http://localhost:8000/index/result
```

I've added  the link like this:

```
<a href="index">Start over </a>
```

As a result,the link directs to:

```
http://localhost:8000/index/result/index
```

instead of the required:

```
http://localhost:8000/index
```

I have all the pages set in urls.py and views.py.

Any help is appreciated. tnx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<a href="/index">Start over </a>
```

or even better

```
<a href="{% url "index" %}">Start over </a>
```

Comment: The second suggestion [will only work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url) with Django >= 1.5 (unreleased) or the `{% load url from future %}` statement. You mean `{% url index %}`.

Comment: My group was having trouble and the first suggestion worked for us.

Answer (score 5):

To build on Daniel Roseman's correct answer, this is nothing to do with Django; you'd experience this issue with plain HTML.

Adding `/` at the start of a URL as Daniel is suggesting (or specifying a protocol) turns it into an absolute link. Starting with an arbitrary name causes the browser to treat it as a relative link. There's a [lot out there explaining the difference](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm), but it's actually pretty simple. Assuming you have the following files:

```
/var/www/html/
├── directory/
│   └── three.html
├── two.html
└── one.html
```

Then you could link to the other pages from `one.html` like

```
<a href='two.html'>2</a>
<a href='directory/three.html'>3</a>
```

or

```
<a href='/two.html'>2</a>
<a href='/directory/three.html'>3</a>
```

And you can link to other pages from `three.html` like

```
<a href='../one.html'>2</a>
<a href='../two.html'>2</a>
```

(`../` means "go up one level).

or

```
<a href='/one.html'>2</a>
<a href='/two.html'>2</a>
```

So when you make a Django template with a link like `<a href="index">Start over</a>`, it adds the `href` value to the URL of the current page, treating it like a relative link.